# Printable html is not breaking new page on Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, printing

I'm trying to create a html report, and I would like to print it. To do this, I'm using AngularPrint (https://github.com/samwiseduzer/angularPrint).

My problem, is that on Firefox, the report is printing in unique page, but the content is overflowing to out of the page.

If I test with Google Chrome, when the same report is creating a new page automatcly to avoid the overflow of the content.

I tryed to use a native window.print, like it (but its happening the same thing):

```
$scope.printReport = function(myhtml) {
  var content = document.getElementById(myhtml).innerHTML;
  var original = document.body.innerHTML;        
  document.body.innerHTML = content;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = original;
}
```

My html code using AngularPrint:

```
<!-- printable area -->
<div class="content" print-section>
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

Button to print:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnPrinReport" print-btn> Print Data </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use css media queries instead of replacing the dom? it would be something like this

```
@media print
{
  .content{
     position:fixed;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     min-width:100vw;
     min-height:100vh;
   }
}
```

and in your java script just have to do something like this

```
$scope.printReport = function(myhtml) {
 window.print();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried do this, my table (that show the data) was not shown.